# C++ JNI call to Java which makes a JNI call to a different C++ DLL

Tags: java-native-interface

I have a Java program that makes JNI calls to a C++ DLL that I compiled.  This works fine.

However, in order to integrate my Java program into a C++ GUI I am working on (don't ask why I need to do this), I am trying to wrap that Java code in a C++ JNI call.  Effectively I am trying:

C++ code makes JNI call to Java.  (This works fine)
Java makes a JNI call to a different C++ DLL that I compiled.

I can load the C++ DLL no problem in Java, but when I try to make the second JNI call to the C++ DLL it just seems to quietly ignore the call and immediately exits the Java function without finishing it, but it does return back to the original C++ code and finished executing fine (so it doesn't crash).

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?  Is there something special I need to do to load the C++ DLL (it is also dependent on other DLLs, but these are all on my path)?

Thanks,
-Zach

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out.  Calling from C++ through JNI to Java and then through JNI again to a different C++ DLL is possible, I just needed to get all my DLLs and jars on the proper paths.